# Limit posts per page depending on the size of a div?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization

I have a custom post type where I can publish posts to be shown on a page which is a static size. When I get to many posts it will continue past the dock (which looks awful). So my question is if it is possible to adjust the number of posts on the fly, depending on how large the div containing the post is?
Because right now I cannot set a number, because a long post will mess this up.

Is there a chance to target a specific div, and if that grows larger than say 85% it will set a maximum post number and paginate?

I am using a multisite if this affects anything?

I really don't know if this is the way to do it, but it is the only thing I can come up with.

Thank you!

Comment: You would need to do this with JavaScript, meaning you would need to also implement pagination with JavaScript, which means you'd probably want to be using the REST API for retrieving and listing posts. Why not just have scrolling?

Comment: Because the site is static and not scrollable, as it will be displayed on a TV only.

Comment: How do you fetch custom post type result? Sample code will be more helpful.